# After updating android studio and new sdk am getting the "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. How can I fix that?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Here is the error am getting when i try to build the app

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

And these are the dependencies am using in my project

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'

    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.0'


    compile 'in.srain.cube:grid-view-with-header-footer:1.0.12'
    compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.1'

    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev2-1.21.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'

    compile 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your GPS is up to date in the SDK Manager?

Comment: @OrhanC1 GPS? did you mean gpu debugging tools?

Comment: Google Play Services.

Comment: @OrhanC1 yes its up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 2 days of searching in web i finally found a solution.
i put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of my build.gradle file. 
But i still don't understand why it didn't work when i write it on top.

May google knows  :P